# Context deadline exceeded

Tags: selenoid

Selenoid is throwing context deadline exceeded after the tests runs for a while. Initially tests runs fine but somewhere after 15-20 mins, it starts throwing exceptions.

**Selenoid and Selenoid-ui is run using commands:**

./selenoid -conf /home/ec2-user/browsers.json -limit 10 -retry-count 3 -session-attempt-timeout 4m -log-output-dir /home/ec2-user/selenoid-logs -timeout 4m -video-recorder-image "selenoid/video-recorder:latest-release"

./selenoid-ui

**Error from console:**

**selenoid-ui**

2019/08/05 18:18:30 [ERROR] [Can't get status: context deadline exceeded]
2019/08/05 18:19:07 Removed client. 0 registered clients

**selenoid**

2019/08/05 18:04:19 [4093] [CLIENT_DISCONNECTED] [unknown] [xx.xx.xx.xx] [Error: context canceled]
2019/08/05 18:06:44 [4102] [CLIENT_DISCONNECTED] [unknown] [xx.xx.xx.xx] [Error: context canceled]
2019/08/05 18:14:24 [4107] [SESSION_DELETED] [4c4d9e47a8853ba972476cb70ffde4a3]
2019/08/05 18:17:44 [4107] [CLIENT_DISCONNECTED] [unknown] [xx.xx.xx.xx] [Error: context canceled]
2019/08/05 18:18:35 [4105] [CLIENT_DISCONNECTED] [unknown] [xx.xx.xx.xx] [Error: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:33292: i/o timeout]

**Test Infrastructure**

1) AWS EC2 t2.micro 1 cpu 
2) NightwatchJS 1.1.11 
3) Chrome 75.0

**Additional Issue**

I see no sessions logs saved in -log-output-dir and dir has the write permissions.

Tried giving session timeout with 4m but it is not helping.

Comment: This seems to be a firewall issue. Could you try to completely stop it and see whether it helps?

Comment: @vania-pooh unfortunately, we are inside enterprise network and we cannot turn-off firewall or rather not allowed to turn-off firewall.

Comment: @vania-pooh the only things which has helped so far is making sure the tests do not run more than 60 secs. If tests are small, they all run fine consistently. But one of our problem is also that breaking our tests into smaller tests is not feasible all the time.